# What's the sorting algorithm when using Array.prototype.sort() with a compare function

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm, sorting

I've known that when using `Array.prototype.sort()`, different browsers have their own sorting algorithm implementation. But I'm curious, does using it with a compare function still utilizes the same sorting algorithm as using without the compare function? If it does, does the compare function have a performance impact on the algorithm? And if it doesn't, what sorting algorithm does it use?

Scenario e.g.

```
const arr = [23, 1, 5, 2, 10, 2]
arr.sort((a, b) => a - b)
```

Comment: "*does using it with a compare function still utilise the same sorting algorithm like using without the compare function*" - why wouldn't it?

Comment: A compare function just tells about the relation between the two given arguments. It is the implementation algorithm, which decides the arguments to compare, and then the place of the given arguments in the original array after the compare function returns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it's the same sort function. Technically when not passing a comparison function it is still using a comparison function as a default. Mozilla has a pretty detailed explanation of the comparison function it uses when none is supplied: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort#Description